# Round integer values inside gridview in Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

How can i check a value inside a gridview cell and round it based on it's value?

For example: [image: gridview]

I want values that end like that (19.999) to be rounded to 20.000, (49.999) to 50.000, etc..

I tried with gridview rowOptions but didn't work.

```
'rowOptions' => function ($model) {
     if ($model->val_liq_moeda % 10 != 0) {
        $model->val_liq_moeda = round($model->val_liq_moeda, -1);
     }                        
},
```

Also that Val_liq_moeda is a column from another table. I'm displaying it here using a join but when i try to access it using $model->val_liq_moeda it says

> Unkonw property

Should i have to declare it as a variable in model?

Thanks!

Comment: @ldg my colum has int numbers, not float

Answer (score 0):

```
'rowOptions' => function ($model) {
    $model->val_liq_moeda = round($model->val_liq_moeda, 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

}
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php